# How to set missing values for all numeric variables

Tags: macros, spss

I have a large dataset with both string and numeric data. The syntax `MISSING VALUES ALL (999).` did not work because SPSS requires numeric and string variables to be listed separately.
It will be a pain to use `MISSING VALUES var1 to varn (999)` command because variables are mixed.

Is there a way to define missing values for all numeric variables at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done using `spssinc select variables` [Extension Command](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ab16c38e-2f7b-4912-a47e-85682d124d32/entry/increasingthegeneralityofspssstatisticsjobsthespssincselectvariablesextensioncommand?lang=en). This command puts a list of variables, prepared according to defined contributes, into a macro name. You can then use the macro name in further commands:

```
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!NumVars" /PROPERTIES TYPE=NUMERIC.
MISSING VALUES !NumVars (999).
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful!